# 関数の戻り値が正しくない

Tags: vba, excel

＜概要＞
関数の呼び出し先と呼び出し元の値が一致しない

＜詳細＞
Excel 2013にて「入力シート」内の下記関数を別シートのマクロ（ボタンに登録）から呼び出しました。
この関数は戻り値として必ずTrueしか返さないはずです。

```
Public Function Test() As Boolean
    Test = Ture
End Function
```

呼び出し元（標準モジュール「Module1」）は下記となります。

```
Dim ResultTest As Boolean
ResultTest = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name).Worksheets("入力シート").Test
```

この時、ResultTestの値はFalseとなります。
ステップ実行するとTest()関数の中に入り、たしかにTest = Trueのパスを通るのですが、戻り値は必ずFalseとなります。
原因は何でしょうか。

＜環境＞
OS:Windows10 Pro
バージョン：1809
Microsoft Office：Microsoft Office 2013
Excel：Excel 2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trueのスペルが間違ってません？Tureになってる。
Testの中、もう一度確認してください

Comment: すみません、恥ずかしい間違いをしてしまいました。
Option Explicitを付けていなかったこともあり、エラーが出なかったのでミススペルしてると思っていませんでした。
TureがデフォルトFalseの変数になりそれを代入していた為、Falseとなっていたようです
ありがとうございました。